# Object Key via Value

Tags: javascript, object

So I'm trying to get object keys via the values to save time having to create a duplicate object with reversed keys and values.

Whether it be a function that returns the key from the value or if there is a builtin method that I missed, I don't really care. I just need a way to get the key.

Example:

```
var user = {'name':'john', 'age':26, 'gender':'male'}
getKey(user.male) // Would return 'gender'?
```

Is there an easy way to get it or would a function be required?

Comment: Why? And what if two keys have the same value? And what have you tried?

Comment: What is the expected returned value? It is quite clear that it would be `"gender"` every time.

Comment: @Phil I'm not asking for the code, I'm asking if there is a way to get the key, via the value.

Comment: @Spedwards: So you'd be satisfied if the only answer you received was *"Yes... yes there is."*?

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes, and a short example to get me on the right track. Not the whole code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The straight forward approach would be simply looping over the object and checking the value:

```
getKey = function (object, value) {
    for (var key in object) {
        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        if (object[key] == value) return key;
    }

    return undefined;
}
```

Demo:

```
> getKey({'name':'john', 'age':26, 'gender':'male'}, 'male');
'gender'
```

Comment: What if two values are the same?

Comment: @thefourtheye It returns the first it encounters, behaving similarly to `String.indexOf` and `Array.indexOf`

Comment: If you want to check for more, create a blank array, push keys to that, return array at end of loop.

Comment: @thefourtheye For the object I am using, there is no key that has the same value.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. There are a few but it doesn't matter for what I used it for :P

Answer (score 1):

Can always modify the `Object` prototype:

```
Object.prototype.getByValue = function(value) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (this[key] == value)
                arr.push(key);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

var user = {'name':'john', 'age':26, 'gender':'male'}
var keys = user.getByValue("male");
console.log(keys); //["gender"]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7jXu2/

Comment: And you have an implicit global.

Comment: @cookiemonster -- Where is the implicit global?\

Comment: By declaring `key` without using `var`, you've implicitly created a global variable. Always use `var` to declare your variables.

Comment: @cookiemonster -- Ahh shit, completely missed that - thanks for looking out!

Answer (score 1):

Like:

```
function getKeys(obj, val){
  var a = [];
  for(var i in obj){
    if(obj[i] === val){
      a.push(i);
    }
  }
  if(a.length > 0){
    return a;
  }
  return 0;
}
var user = {name:'john', age:26, gender:'male'};
var males = getKeys(user, 'male');
if(males){
  for(var i in males){
    console.log(males[i]);
  }
}
else{
  console.log('No males were found');
}
```

Now you can get multiple keys!